# How to include an equation model in python code

Tags: python

So um I wanted to know how to include an equational model in python such that I put in the values and get the output according to the equation . Like for example if my model was x^2 + y^2 = output. How do I incorporate this model into my code , so that when I give values for x and y I get the output .

Comment: Write it as a function.

Comment: Look at function definitions in Python

Comment: link to python math operations : https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Basic_Math

Comment: In python `^` is treated as XOR so you might want to look for operators in Python as well. You can use `**`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html) for cleaner calculations

```
from sympy import *
x = Symbol('x')  # define first symbol
y = Symbol('y')  # define second symbol

output = x**2 + y**2 # form the equation

print(output) # print the equation on console
```

**Output**

```
x**2 + y**2
```

Now substitute the values of x and y like we do in any math equation

```
output.subs({x:1,y:1}) #substitue x::1 and y::1 to get the result
```

**Output**

```
2 # 1**2 ==1 and 1**2==1 and 1+1 =2
```

For completeness, you can define the equation inside the function as well but it will be less descriptive for complex equations

```
def func(x,y): return x**2 + y**2
```

Now you can use the function to get the output

```
func(1,1) #2
```

Answer (score 1):

A function can receive one or more inputs, and return a value: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp

```
def my_equation(x, y):
    return x**2 + y**2
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this,

1. @paritosh-singh said, write it as a function
2. use a library that allows you to do symbolic calculations, such as [sympy](https://www.sympy.org)

with sympy, you can do this as

```
from sympy import *
x, y, z= symbols('x y z')
z = (x^2)+(y^2)
```

you can now assign values to x and y and get output as z.

sympy [documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html)